# Vim Search and Replace

Tags: vim

I have a file that contains a SQL statement that looks like this that I paste in from some code.  Can someone tell me the search/replace command for changing the `+ "` values to blank or null?

I've tried various combinations of this but nothing seems to work

```
:%s\x ",,

  " select"
+ " col1 "
+ " col1 "
+ " col1 "
+ " col1 "
+ " from table"
```

Answer (score 7):

`:%s/+\|"//g`

Explanation:

`%s` - Search the whole file

`/` - Separator character

`+\|"` Search for the string `+` or the string `"`

`/` - Separator character

- Replace with nothing

`/` - Separator character

`g` - "Global" replace (without this it would only do one substitution per line)

Substitutions are in the form `range to look at/what to look for/what to replace with/options`

The separator character can be anything, `/` is just the most common. Personally, I like `;` because it makes it easier to read when you have a bunch of backslashes.

Comment: An alternative: `:%s/[+"]//g`  (a little easier to read)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
:%s/["+]//g
```

This assumes that you want to remove all `"` and `+` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:%s/+ "//
```

Assuming you want to remove all '+ "' strings

Comment: I believe the OP **also** wants to remove the `"` characters at the end of each line.